# OCSP validation - unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-14.04, ocsp

I'm new to setup SSL from the scratch and did my first steps. I bought a SSL cert from RapidSSL for my domain and followed there steps to install the cert. 
In general the cert is valid and working on my webserver(nginx v1.4.6 - Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS), but if I'm trying to activate OCSP OCSP I get the following error in my nginx error.log:

> OCSP_basic_verify() failed (SSL: error:27069065:OCSP
>   routines:OCSP_basic_verify:certificate verify error:Verify
>   error:unable to get local issuer certificate) while requesting
>   certificate status, responder: gv.symcd.com

I tried it also with this command from the command line:

> openssl s_client -connect mydomain.tld:443 2>&1 < /dev/null

And got the "same" error like in my error.log:

> [...]SSL-Session:
>       Protocol  : TLSv1.2
>       Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
>    [...]
>       Start Time: 1411583991
>       Timeout   : 300 (sec)
>       Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)

But if download the GeoTrust Root Certificat and try it with this command:

> openssl s_client -connect mydomain.tld:443 -CAfile GeoTrust_Global_CA.pem 2>&1 < /dev/null

Verification is ok:

> [...]SSL-Session:
>       Protocol  : TLSv1.2
>       Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
>    [...]
>       Start Time: 1411583262
>       Timeout   : 300 (sec)
>       Verify return code: 0 (ok)

So somehow the GeoTrust Root Cert isn't found/delivered.

My nginx site config:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name mydomain.tld;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl.key;


    # Resumption
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;

    # Timeout
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    # Security options
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    # OCSP Stapling
    # It means that you sent status info about your certificate along with the request,
    # instead of making the browser check the certificate with the Certificate Authority.
    # This removes a large portion of the SSL overhead, the CloudFlare post above explains it in more detail.
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    #ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl.pem;

    #resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    #resolver_timeout 10s;

    # This forces every request after this one to be over HTTPS
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";[...]};
```

RapidSSL wrote in his documentation that I should add the following certificates into the ssl.crt with the following order:

1. myserver.crt
2. Intermediate CA Bundle (RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3)
3. Intermediate CA Bundle (GeoTrust Global CA)

So I did...

Right now I've no idea what I'm doing wrong... hopefully anyone here can help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Those two errors was unrelated although the error message was same.

> [...]SSL-Session: Protocol : TLSv1.2 Cipher : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 [...] Start Time: 1411583991 Timeout : 300 (sec) Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Above error was issued **openssl_client** command. As explained by Florian Heigl, you get this error because the openssl_client need the Globalsign Root cert in `/etc/ssl/certs`.

---

> OCSP_basic_verify() failed (SSL: error:27069065:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:certificate verify error:Verify error:unable to get local issuer certificate) while requesting certificate status, responder: gv.symcd.com

For this error, it was issued by **nginx ocsp routine**, especially when you add `ssl_stapling_verify on;` line in nginx.conf.

Here some excerpt from [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_stapling_verify) of `ssl_stapling_verify` to explain why it throws the error

> Syntax:   ssl_stapling_verify on | off;
>
> Enables or disables verification of OCSP responses by the server.
>
> For verification to work, **the certificate of the server certificate issuer, the root certificate, and all intermediate certificates** should be configured as trusted using the ssl_trusted_certificate directive.

In other words, you need provide **(2) Intermediate CA Bundle (RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3)** and **(3) Intermediate CA Bundle (GeoTrust Global CA)** to `ssl_trusted_certificate` directive.

```
cat GeoTrustGlobalCA.crt rapidsslG3.crt > ocsp-chain.crt
```

and add `ocsp-chain.crt` to `ssl_trusted_certificate` directive.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried this also, but always tested it with the cli command.

Comment: Where do we get the intermediate certs?

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer part of this.

openssl s_client -connect mydomain.tld:443 2>&1 < /dev/null

would need the Globalsign Root cert in /etc/ssl/certs.
There is a ca-certificates package, do you have that installed?

Comment: I don't understand why to use Globalsign Root cert when dealing with RapidSSL and GeoTrust?? they are different from Globalsign... correct me if I was wrong!